# How can I get the IP of a hostname using a fixed DNS server?

Tags: c, unix, networking, dns, tcp

Is there an easy way, on *nix platforms(Linux specifically) to get the IP address of a hostname, while supplying a custom DNS server to use in place of the system's configured one? I want to access this information from a C program.

Comment: Writing a DNS query packet takes about 10-20 lines of code; it's easy to do yourself if you RTFM RFC 1035. Processing the response is slightly more work but still easy.

Comment: @R..: Ease up, use of RTFM isn't necessary here. If you'd answered with a link to RFC 1035 I'd have upvoted it.

Comment: Sorry, I sometimes forget RTFM isn't seen as affectionate except outside of some of my circles. I probably would have made that an answer if I'd bothered to go get the link and add a few more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use your own resolver, directly sending DNS packets, instead of relying on the system's resolver and `gethostbyname`. You would probably want to use a library, such as [adns](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~ian/adns/).

Answer (score 2):

```
nslookup <hostname> <dns server>
```

For example:

```
nslookup www.example.com ns1.example.com
```

Comment: I was looking to get this information from a C program(and not using system() :) ). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case, can you clarify your question to specify that?  You did not mention C in the question at all.